# Image selector in custom widget

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I am quite new to Apostrophe and loving it.

But, I am trying to implement an image selector (from apostrophe-images) in a custom widget.

This is my index.js

```js
module.exports = {        
 extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',        
 label: 'Slider Slide',        
addFields: [
 {
  name: 'line1',
  label: 'Line 1',
  type: 'string'
},
{
  name: 'line2',
  label: 'Line 2',
  type: 'string'
},
{
  name: 'description',
  label: 'Description',
  type: 'string',
  textarea: true
},
{
  name: 'buttontext',
  label: 'Button Text',
  type: 'string'
},
{
  name: 'buttonlink',
  label: 'Button Link',
  type: 'string'
 },
 {
    name: '_background',
    type: 'joinByOne',
    withType: 'apostrophe-image',
    label: 'background',
    idField: 'backgroundId'
  }      
]        
};
```

This all works fine to create the content.

When I try and access the image in the widget.html of the module:

```
{{ apos.attachments.url(data.widget._background, { size: 'full' }) }}
```

I get the following returned.

```
 /uploads/attachments/cjff74abn000w9zac6l8hjdnh-undefined.undefined
```

Any help would be appreciated to where I am going wrong. I have read all the tutorials on joining widget buts can't seem to understand the undefined.undefined.

Thanks

Comment: This should work. Can you push up a simple project that demonstrates the problem to github? Glad to take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `attachment` property to the url helper

try

```
{{ apos.attachments.url(data.widget._background.attachment, { size: 'full' }) }}
```